# Tightened the bolts on the bottom of my suspension fork -- What now?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork

So... a few hours ago I did a bolt check on my bike. As I was about finished I checked the 2 bolts on the bottom of each of the fork's legs. They were kinda easy to tighten so I said to myself go for it without even thinking about it. I did about 1/4 or half a turn and then the bolt started to turn with almost no force both clock and counter-clock-wise. When I push into it's not as smooth. It almost feels like parts are rubbing? Not sure how to explain it. I cant find the model of the fork but the bike is a 2016 ideal zigzag 27"5. It only says SRT on it. If any of you can help in any way that would be great thanks.

Comment: Photos would help. Are the bolts in question your axle bolts?

Comment: Damper adjustment or pre-tensioning screw?

Comment: Are these 2 bolts the preload and damper adjustment bolts?

Comment: Edited the title of this post.  Hopefully this helps it get more attention.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Hop you haven’t stripped a thread, which sometimes explains sudden lack of resistance!

Comment: First of all thanks for the feedback. Didn't expect to draw attention at all... for some reason I can't upload the photo here so I uploaded at imgur. That's the link http://imgur.com/a/qYOW . The screw that I'm talking about is the left one. It's on the side of the preload adjuster if that helps at all. Also there is a pretty noticeable clicking sound when the fork is compressed about 65% of the way. I'm kinda afraid to ride it on trails ...

Comment: I also visited the shop I got it from but he only said that it's broken without even checking it first and that guarantee won't fix it for free. To be honest though I don't take the word of any mechanic here. Every single one of them does a really sloppy job at something as simple as changing a tube... When i first got into mtbing I asked him about lubing chain and he told me to bring it to him a couple of times a year and he'll do it with his spray on black grease... I clean my drivetrain almost every week now depending on the trails I ride.